# Performance solutions of MySQL subqueries

Tags: mysql, performance, subquery

I have 2 tables like below:

Table media:

```
+---------------------------------------------------------+
| media_id | media_name  | media_category  | media_status |
+---------------------------------------------------------+
| 1        | item1       | 2               | true         |
| 2        | item2       | 2               | true         |
| 3        | item3       | 1               | false        |
| 4        | item3       | 1               | false        |
| 5        | item3       | 1               | true         |
+---------------------------------------------------------+
```

Table category:

```
+--------------------+ 
| cat_id | cat_name  | 
+--------------------+ 
| 1      | blue      | 
| 2      | red       | 
| 3      | white     | 
| 4      | green     | 
+--------------------+
```

I wish to retrieve for all categories the number of associated medias by status.

So in my example, the result must be:

```
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+ 
| cat_id | cat_name  | countMediaTotal | countMediaActive  | countMediaInactive  |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+ 
| 1      | blue      | 3               | 1                 | 2                   |
| 2      | red       | 2               | 2                 | 0                   |
| 3      | white     | 0               | 0                 | 0                   |
| 4      | green     | 0               | 0                 | 0                   |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

My actual SQL request:

```
SELECT *,   
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM media AS MED WHERE CAT.cat_id = MED.media_category) AS countMediaTotal, 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM media AS MED WHERE CAT.cat_id = MED.media_category AND media_status = 'true') AS countMediaActive, 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM media AS MED WHERE CAT.cat_id = MED.media_category AND media_status = 'false') AS countMediaInactive 
FROM `category` AS CAT
```

There are 3 similar subqueries.

Is there a more powerful solution to achieve this or is it the best?

Comment: What does "best" mean? (Rhetorical.) You have some naive vague notion of some query expression(s) being reasonably vaguely describable by an everyday word. A technical meaning involves engineering tradeoffs given a context. Please read about 'program optimization' & 'query optimization'. You could start with the tag info.

Comment: Yes you are right. I thought only performances

Comment: Unfortunately all of my comment applies to other vaugely more specific words like "performance" (whatever you mean by that--what aspect do you mean of what being performed?) or "speed". Any reasonable technical meaning involves very many factors.

Comment: Ok! So how to ask the question of an SQL query that would require fewer resources for the SQL engine or the server and which returns the results faster to the client?

Comment: Please see my first comment. Your question is too broad. Even the simplest googling shows this.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
SELECT c.cat_id, c.cat_name,   
COUNT(*) AS countMediaTotal, 
SUM(IF(m.media_status = 'true', 1, 0)) AS countMediaActive, 
SUM(IF(m.media_status = 'false', 1, 0)) AS countMediaInactive 
FROM `category` AS c
LEFT JOIN media m ON m.media_category = c.cat_id
GROUP BY c.cat_id, c.cat_name
```

Comment: Most probably. Your subqueries get executed for each row in your category table. You can also do a `EXPLAIN <query>` to see if and how indexes are used. And finally, all you have to do is measure ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this...

```
SELECT c.*
     , COALESCE(m.media_status,0) media_status
     , COUNT(0) total 
  FROM category c 
  LEFT 
  JOIN media m 
    ON c.cat_id = m.media_category 
 GROUP 
    BY c.cat_id
     , m.media_status;
```

... and handle any remaining display issues in application code.